# Check if image exists, if not load it

Tags: ajax, jquery

I need to load an image if if hasn't been loaded yet.
For this i'm using the error function like this:

```
$.ajax({  
type: "POST",  
url: "inc/functions.php",  
data: { productID: productIDVal, action: "addToCart"},  
success: function(theResponse) {
 busy=false;
 $('#buyButton')
  .error(function(){
   var t = $("<img id='buyButton' src='images/checkout.png' />");
   $.append(t);
 });
}  
});
```

But it is not working. Am i doing something wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you need: `$(this).append(t);`

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify where to append the image:

```
$('#buyButton').append(t);  // NOT $.append(t);
// OR $(this).append(t);
```

More info [here](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

Some general tips on debugging javascript.

Quick and dirty: Put an `alert` message on the first line of the error function like `alert('inside error')`. Then load the page and see if the alert message shows up. You can put variables inside the alert message to see what their values are. If you don't see an alert message it means that the code is not even being loaded for some reason, so you have to put an alert message at an earlier point. (This can get very tedious).

Better way: Start using Firebug or Safari's Web Inspector to debug the javascript. Just put `debugger` anywhere in your code and when the browser gets to that line of code, it will stop and give you a console with access to all variables and functions available at that point in the code.

The problem may be with the AJAX request. See what it is returning by trying this code:

```
$.ajax({  
  type: "POST",  
  url: "inc/functions.php",  
  data: { productID: productIDVal, action: "addToCart"},
  success: function(data){ alert('success!'); },
  error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){ alert(errorThrown) ;}
})
```

You can replace the `alert` messages with `debugger` to do further inspection of what is going on with Firebug.

Comment: the strange thing is that when doing debugging like alert("image doesnt exist"); it does not trigger it either.

Comment: @zarfrada , you should move that to error block right and backend should throw an error also to reproduce that

Comment: @zafrada , one more thing do you have id with buyButton for sure///

Comment: @zarfrada Are you sure your ajax request is returning successfully? Try adding an alert message to the first line of the `success` function. I advise you to use a debugging console. Please see updated answer for more info.

Comment: @gov: well, if #buyButton doesnt exist it should create it and assign it the id. var t = $("<img id='buyButton' src='images/checkout.png' />");

Comment: @zafrada , why will it create , it just appends to existing dom right

Comment: @browsersenior: just tried putting an alert on the error function and indeed it is not being loaded. i will try using firebug

Comment: according to firebug's net panel, this function is indeed being loaded. i put alert(); in several parts and got none of them to popup. i have no clue on what's wrong

Comment: @zafrada Look at my updated answer for some info on how to debug the AJAX request. First step is to make sure the AJAX request is executing without error.

Answer (score 0):

you should move the code to error block

remove from the success block

```
error: function(request,error) {
  var t = $("<img id='buyButton' src='images/checkout.png' />");
   $(this).append(t);
  }
```

the skeleton goes like this

```
$.ajax({

 },
 beforeSend: function() {

 },

 error: function(request,error) {
  var t = $("<img id='buyButton' src='images/checkout.png' />");
   $(this).append(t);
  },
  success: function(request) {

  } // End success
}); // End ajax method
```

Comment: just tried this, same results. the image is not being loaded.

Comment: adding an alert(""); is not triggered either

Comment: @zafrada , do you have id for sure buyButton

Comment: then something wrong with your ajax, open firebug and check net panel whether your ajax succeeded or not

Comment: according to firebug's net panel, this function is indeed being loaded. i put alert(); in several parts and got none of them to popup. i have no clue on what's wrong